# Godot body_exit function using area 2D

Tags: godot

I am trying to create a code where my mob is able to chase the player when they are in the area set . My code works when the player enters the area but does not work when the player exits the are. I think the problem lies in the signal for body_exit but when i check it does not seem to have any problem. This code is from a tutoiral form freecodecamp godot tutorial 2D platformer game. Much thanks for helping out.

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var SPEED = 50
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var player
var chase = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    #Gravity for Frog
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if chase == true:
        if get_node("AnimatedSprite2D").animation != "Death":
            get_node("AnimatedSprite2D").play("Jump")
        player = get_node("../../Player/Player")
        var direction = (player.position - self.position).normalized()
        if direction.x > 0:
            get_node("AnimatedSprite2D").flip_h = true
        else:
            get_node("AnimatedSprite2D").flip_h = false
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = 0
    move_and_slide()
    
func _on_player_detection_body_entered(body):

    if body.name == "Player":
        chase = true
        
func _on_player_detection_body_exited(body):
    if body.name == "Player":
        chase = false
```

So i tried to debug by printing statements in the function when the player is not in the area. However, the thing is there is no print statements found. So i cant seem to tell what is the problem

Comment: Is the body_exited signal of the Area2D connected to your script?

Comment: yes it is. However , the code does not work

Comment: try [connecting the signal in the script](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html#connecting-a-signal-via-code) itself and see it that works ( you may need [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html#connecting-a-signal-via-code) if you're using godot version 3.5)